# Nested Swift 4 Codable Struct uses CodingKeys irregularly

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

I have some JSON that I'm trying to decode with a Swift struct that conforms to the Codable protocol.  The main struct doesn't seem to want to recognize the codingKey alias for thread_type, but happily consumes the explicitly named `thread_id` attribute. The struct in question is below:

```
struct Message: Codable {
var id: String?
var type: String?
var thread_id: String?
var threadType: String?
var sender: User?
var body: String?
var media: String?
var sentAt: Double?
var unread: Bool?
var status: String?
var url: String?

enum codingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case type
    case thread_id
    case threadType = "thread_type"
    case sender
    case body
    case media
    case sentAt = "sent_at"
    case unread
    case status
    case url
}
}
```

The JSON that I'm trying to parse:

```
let json =
"""
{
"id": "Jvbl6LY",
"type": "sms",
"thread_id": "60LrVL7",
"thread_type": "578a",
"delay_until": null,
"sender": {
"id": "EVkdNBx",
"type": "user",
"first_name": "Jerry",
"last_name": "Ward",
"mobile_number": "123-456-7890",
"profile_image_url": "",
"is_online": false,
"email": "jerryw+demo@jypsee.com"
},
"body": "Here is a picture of our Coquille Suite.  Let me know if you would like a reservation?",
"media": "",
"sent_at": 1509133604000.167,
"unread": false,
"status": "",
"url": "https://connect-staging.jypsee.com/api/sms/threads/60LrVL7/history/Jvbl6LY/"
}
"""
```

And finally the decoder call itself:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let message = try decoder.decode(Message.self, from: data)
    print(message.thread_id)
    print(message.threadType)
    print(message.sender?.firstName)
    print(message.sender?.lastName)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The message.thread_id prints `Optional("60LrVL7")\n"` which is expected. 
The message.threadType prints `nil\n`, which is not expected.  Even more bizarre is the fact that message.sender?.firstName and message.sender?.lastName both print `"Optional("Jerry")\n"` and `"Optional("Ward")\n"` respectively.  Which means the nested User Codable Struct CodingKey IS working.  I'm really at a loss as to why there's such an inconsistency in decoding.

[Xcode Playground Gist is available here](https://gist.github.com/jamesjmtaylor/3bf2c846a4c0a4700d1e0fa6a0389a7f)

Comment: `CodingKeys`, not `codingKeys`.

Comment: Doh!  Amazing what an extra set of eyes can do.  Thank you!

Comment: Is every field really optional? You can be sent `{}` and you would expect to decode that as all nils (and you'd consider those nils different than empty strings or false)? The fact that `profile_image_url` is being sent as `""` makes that very suspicious. Using this many optionals is typically a sign of a data problem.

Comment: `CodingKeys` should be a `private enum`.

Comment: Should be, but they don't have to be for them to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doc clearly states in the first sentence on the paragraph below. **A special enumeration named 'CodingKeys' is necessary**. (I had the similar problem and took me quite some time to find out).

[image]
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types